# Returning JSON array rom database response (lumen php)

Tags: php, arrays, json, lumen

i am trying to sort the response i recive from my database to return a nice JSON array but i cant find how to do it and so i turn to you for help.

The response from the database:

```
[{"stad":"\u00d6rebro","lokalnamn":"Allm\u00e4nrepan"}, 
{"stad":"Kumla","lokalnamn":"Rum 1"},{"stad":"Kumla","lokalnamn":"Rum 
2"}, 
{"stad":"Kumla","lokalnamn":"Rum 4"}, 
{"stad":"Karlstad","lokalnamn":"UNO"}, 
{"stad":"Karlstad","lokalnamn":"Replokal 231"}]
```

i would like it to return something like:

```
[
"\u00d6rebro":{"Allm\u00e4nrepan"},
"kumla":{"Rum 1","Rum 2","rum 4"},
"Karlstad":{"uno","replokal 231"}
]
```

hope you get the point,

have tried to call response->json() on array, without success and i cant find any further information online as im not sure what to search for

Comment: can you please post the JSON in correct format

Comment: The above looks like ugly but valid JSON, @rs007. What exactly do you want changed?

Comment: @TOBE does my post answer you or you use different format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by following those steps:

1. create an array with key-value according your json
2. modify element with 1 value only to not be an array (using [array-map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php))

Consider this code as example:

```
$s = '[{"stad":"\u00d6rebro","lokalnamn":"Allm\u00e4nrepan"},{"stad":"Kumla","lokalnamn":"Rum 1"},{"stad":"Kumla","lokalnamn":"Rum 2"},{"stad":"Kumla","lokalnamn":"Rum 4"},{"stad":"Karlstad","lokalnamn":"UNO"},{"stad":"Karlstad","lokalnamn":"Replokal 231"}]';

$arr = json_decode($s, true);
$res = array();
foreach($arr as $elem) {
    $key = $elem["stad"];
    $value = $elem["lokalnamn"];
    if (array_key_exists($key, $res)) {
        $res[$key][] = $value;
    } else {
        $res[$key] = array($value);
    }
}

$a = array_map(function($elem) {
    if (is_array($elem) && count($elem) == 1)
        return $elem[0];
    else return $elem;
},$res);
```

This will give you:

```
Array
(
    [Örebro] => Allmänrepan
    [Kumla] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rum 1
            [1] => Rum 2
            [2] => Rum 4
        )

    [Karlstad] => Array
        (
            [0] => UNO
            [1] => Replokal 231
        )
)
```